# NodeJS: Convert string X,XXX.XX to float

Tags: node.js, string, floating-point, string-parsing

I'm bothering you because I'm looking to convert a string into a float with node.JS. 
I have a string that comes back from a request and looks like: 
`x,xxx.xxxx` (ex. `4,530.1200`) and I'd like to convert it to a float: `xxxx.xxxx` (or `4530.1200`).
I've tried to use: 
`parseFloat(str)` but it returns `4`. I also found `Float.valueOf(str)` on the web but I get a `ReferenceError: Float is not defined` error.

Comment: I would use string replace to go around this problem like: `parseFloat('4,530.1200'.replace(/,/g, ''))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was hopping for an existing more direct approach than getting into regex manip' but I worked like a charm so thanks again!
If you want, put it up as an answer so that I can reference it as the solution!

Comment: Just a tip: don't use floating point numbers to represent currency.

Comment: Hmmmm ... ok... :P Why is that (if you have the time to explain)? and what should I use? FYI. The info is being recieved from a request, then manipulated into a specific layout (still an object) and then sent to a mongodb via mongoose.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730040 For Mongoose, there are specific plugins that handle currency values, like [`mongoose-currency`](https://github.com/paulcsmith/mongoose-currency)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use string replace to solve this kind of problem.

```
str = '4,530.1200';
parseFloat(str.replace(/,/g, ''));
```

This will remove all the `,` from your string so that you can convert it to the float using `parseFloat`.

**Notice** the `g` flag in regex, it represents `global`, by using this you are specifying to remove all the matched regex.